# Highcharts Internet Explorer 8.0.6 Issues

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I am using Highcharts Master-Details chart, it is hiding Title and sub title text on IE 8.0.6 and on zooming it hides axes labels. Example from highcharts [Master-Details Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail) has output:

**For IE 8.0.7(not support HTML5) and Firefox, Chrome & other HTML 5 supported Browsers **

[image]

and on zooming:

[image]

**For IE 8.0.6 **

Not showing the title and sub title text:

[image]

on zooming, Hides the axes labels of Detail chart:

[image]

Any suggestions?